# Special character in $wgSitename

Tags: config, mediawiki

How can I add a special character to the name of a wiki?

The name is stored in the variable [$wgSitename](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgSitename)  of LocalSettings.php.
Special characters which are entered directly are not displayed correctly in the title of the browser's tab.

Example line in LocalSettings.php

```
$wgSitename="Fähre"
```

In the resulting page tab title, `ä` is replaced by an unreadable character.

Comment: Please include a [mcve].

Comment: I have included an example.

Comment: Probably an encoding problem with your configuration file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine on my MediaWiki 1.31.1 Install.

If I were you I would make sure the encoding of LocalSettings.php isn't the problem as @Tgr suggested. After saving, open it with a different text editor and note whether it has been replaced by an unreadable character or not.

Not sure if relevant in this case but elsewhere problems have been fixed by making sure php has mbstring enabled. To install it in debian you can use `apt install php-mbstring`

Comment: It seems in fact that this has been an encoding problem in the file, rewriting solved the problem.